# Функция из DLL (на Си) не работает в C#

Tags: c#

Как передать буфер для заполнения в функцию (функция в DLL-ке нап. на Си , исходника нету)
я делаю так

```
> 
[DllImport("hscli.dll" ,  EntryPoint="hcSqlReadResults" ,CharSet=CharSet.Auto , SetLastError=true) ]
    static unsafe extern int hcSqlReadResults(int pOper, long gStart,  byte[] bufOut , uint wBufSize, uint* cntOut);
    long gStart,  byte[] bufOut , uint wBufSize, uint* cntOut);long gStart   = 0 ; // с какой записи начинаем читать 
    uint wBufSize = 0 ; // задаем размер сколько прочитать 
    uint cntOut   = 0 ; // сколько записали в буфер
    byte[] bufOut = new byte[pRecSize * pStr] ;  // буфер для результата
    err = hcSqlReadResults(pOper, gStart, bufOut, pRecSize * (uint)pStr, &cntOut); // Чтение результатов
```

в .h файле к этой DLL эта функция описана так

>

```
 /* Чтение результатов с указанной позиции */
HSCLI_FUN(hcERR) hcSqlReadResults(
  hcHSTMT   h,      /* Оператор с результатами */
  hcRECNO   gStart,     /* С какой записи начинаем читать */
  void      *pBuf,      /* Адрес буфера для результатов */
  unsigned  wBufSize,   /* Размер буфера этого буфера */
  unsigned  *cnt)       /* Сколько прочитали */
    HSCLI_EOF
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57099/discussion-on-question-by-vova-forum---dll------c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ОК ,   решено ,   все дело в типах  ,   надо подбирать  чтобы по байтам сходились, ну и что самое главное на знаковый безнаковый ,

```
[DllImport("hscli.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)] // ф-ция  
static unsafe extern int hcSqlReadResults(                                   // "Чтение результатов"
                                          int pOper,  // Идентификатор оператора
                                          int gStart, // С какой записи начинаем читать
                                          byte[] bufOut, // Адрес буфера для присылаемых записей.
                                          int wBufSize,  // Размер буфера для результатов
                                          out int cntOut ); // Сколько прочитал
int gStart = 0; // с какой записи начинаем читать результат
int wBufSize = (int)pRecSize * pStr; // задаем размер сколько прочитать результат
 byte[] bufOut = new byte[(int)wBufSize]; // буфер для результата
 int cntOut; // сколько записали в буфер результата
 err = hcSqlReadResults(pOper, gStart, bufOut, wBufSize, out cntOut); // Чтение результатов 
textBox4.AppendText("Ф-ция <Чтение результатов> err = " + err.ToString() + "\r\n");
```